# Setting default format on capture device via WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

In an application I've been using the piece of code below to automatically set the 'Default Format' of the microphone to '2 channel, 16 bit, 48000Hz'.

This code works in Windows 7 an 8 en until recently also in Windows 10. Since some update of Windows 10 this year the code doesn't work anymore as expected. When I manually set the format to another value, like 44.1KHz in Sound - Mic - Advanced and I run the code, then the format is changed to '2 channel, 16 bit, 48000Hz', but I get no sound from the microphone. When I set the format manually to the correct value, then there are no problems.

Here is the piece of code:

```
    IMMDevice* pEndpointRead = NULL;
IMMDevice* pEndpointWrite = NULL;
IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator = NULL;
IPropertyStore* propertyStoreRead = NULL;
IPropertyStore* propertyStoreWrite = NULL;
IAudioClient   *audioClient = NULL;
PROPVARIANT propRead;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&pEnumerator);
hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eCapture, eMultimedia, &pEndpointRead);
hr = pEndpointRead->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, &propertyStoreRead);
if (FAILED(hr)) 
{
    std::cout << "OpenPropertyStore failed!" << std::endl;
}
hr = propertyStoreRead->GetValue(PKEY_AudioEngine_DeviceFormat, &propRead);
if (FAILED(hr)) 
{
    std::cout << "GetValue failed!" << std::endl;
}

deviceFormatProperties =(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE *)propRead.blob.pBlobData;
deviceFormatProperties->Format.nChannels = 2;
deviceFormatProperties->Format.nSamplesPerSec = 48000;
deviceFormatProperties->Format.wBitsPerSample = 16;
deviceFormatProperties->Samples.wValidBitsPerSample = deviceFormatProperties->Format.wBitsPerSample;
deviceFormatProperties->Format.nBlockAlign = (deviceFormatProperties->Format.nChannels*deviceFormatProperties->Format.wBitsPerSample) / 8;
deviceFormatProperties->Format.nAvgBytesPerSec = deviceFormatProperties->Format.nSamplesPerSec*deviceFormatProperties->Format.nBlockAlign;
deviceFormatProperties->dwChannelMask = KSAUDIO_SPEAKER_STEREO;
deviceFormatProperties->Format.cbSize = 22;
deviceFormatProperties->SubFormat = KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM;
hr = pEndpointRead->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioClient), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&audioClient);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    std::cout << "pDevice->Activate failed!" << std::endl;
}

hr = audioClient->IsFormatSupported(/*AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED*/AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE, (PWAVEFORMATEX)&deviceFormatProperties->Format, NULL);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    std::cout << "IsFormatSupported failed" << std::endl;
}
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&pEnumerator);
hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eCapture, eMultimedia, &pEndpointWrite);

hr= pEndpointWrite->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_WRITE, &propertyStoreWrite);
if (FAILED(hr)) 
{
    std::cout << "OpenPropertyStore failed!" << std::endl;
}
hr = propertyStoreWrite->SetValue(PKEY_AudioEngine_DeviceFormat, propRead);
if (FAILED(hr)) 
{
    std::cout << "SetValue failed!" << std::endl;
}
hr = propertyStoreWrite->Commit();

pEndpointWrite->Release();
pEnumerator->Release();
propertyStoreWrite->Release();
pEndpointRead->Release();
propertyStoreRead->Release();
pEndpointRead = NULL;
PropVariantClear(&propRead);
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I noticed that if launch the code "As Administrator" it succeeds. the format however is not changed anyway.